# how do I add api token included as a username for each HTTP request i make to an API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having difficulties adding my api token to make http requests on the Worksnaps API.

Here is their documentation explonation but I can't get it to work.
https://www.worksnaps.com/api_docs/worksnaps_api.html

And here is my code:

```
// prepare the header
var headers = {
    //'Content-Type' : 'text/xml',
    //'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8'),
    'Authorization': 'token'
};

// options for GET
    var options_get = {
        host: 'worksnaps.com', // here only the domain name
        // (no http/https !)
        //port : 443,
        path: '/api/projects/' + project_id + '/user_assignments.xml', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
        method: 'GET', // do GET
        headers: headers
    };
```

It always returns status401,which from my knoledge it means Unauthorized.
Any idea?

Comment: are you passing a proper token in the 'Authorization' header? In the link you send, they explain how to generate the token.

Comment: yes, I have the token and I am passing the proper token, I just dont know if I am passing it in the right way how they are saying

Comment: are you calling api.worksnaps.com or worksnaps.com? because in the documentation seems that the host is api.worksnaps.com

Comment: I am calling as I am showing in options_get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs you provided worksnaps uses basic authentication

> Every user has an API token and authentication is managed using HTTP
>   **basic** authentication. In each request the API token has to be included
>   as the username and the **password is ignored** (that is, only the API
>   token is used for authenticating API requests). Example,
>
> curl -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
>   -u hy192jfeh26uiew8yg43mfekb21jfenaxop912f3:ignored -d '...'

so what you're looking for is:

```
var auth_hash = new Buffer(token_string + ":ignored").toString('base64')
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_hash
```

Comment: I still get 401 Unauthorised... and I know I am giving the proper token which I am genereting from their site.

Comment: They are saying the api token has to be included as username, I just dont get this where to add smth like username=token

Comment: okay sorry, your token_string must be base64 encoded before using it with the Authorization header.  you may also have to put some kind of password (even though its just gonna ignore it).

Comment: I am fairly new to node.js same as javascript, how do I encode the string to base64? is there any native function or I should use any library?

Comment: and here we go :) awesome

Answer (score 0):

Based on  [RFC 6750, 2.1. Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) you probably need to add "Bearer" to your header:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_string
```

Comment: it still return 401, they saying to add token as username and leave password blank or ignored, did you check their documentation? I just can't exactly understand what they mean